# Unable to invoke lambda function in api gateway method using cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I am trying to provision Lambda and API Gateway using CloudFormation template and trying to invoke Lambda in one of the method, but getting issue like function arn is invalid. Please provide some resolution on this

{

```
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion":"2010-09-09",

"Transform":"AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",

"Description":"Testing.",

"Parameters":{
   
},
"Conditions":{
   
},
"Resources":{
   "AspNetCoreFunction":{
      "Type":"AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties":{
         "Handler":"<Handler_details>",
         "Runtime":"dotnetcore3.1",
         "CodeUri":"",
         "MemorySize":256,
         "Timeout":30,
         "Role":"$Function_Role",
         "Policies":null,
      }
   },
   "gateway":{
      "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
      "Properties":{
         "Name":"Test",
         "Description":"Testing",
         "ApiKeySourceType":"HEADER",
         "EndpointConfiguration":{
            "Types":[
               "REGIONAL"
            ]
         }
      }
   },            
 
   "ApiMethod":{
      "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::Method",
      "Properties":{
         "RestApiId":{
            "Ref":"gateway"
         },
         "HttpMethod":"ANY",
         "AuthorizationType":"NONE",
         "Integration":{
            "IntegrationHttpMethod":"POST",
            "TimeoutInMillis":29000,
            "Type":"AWS_PROXY",
            "Uri":{
               "Fn::Sub":[
                  "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations",
                  {
                     "lambdaArn":{
                        "Fn::GetAtt":[
                           "AspNetCoreFunction",
                           "Arn"
                           
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }

         }
      }
   }
```

}

I have tried to use below uri, behalf above uri which is mentioned in above code, but still having same issue.

"uri":  "Fn::Sub":["arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${AspNetCoreFunction.Arn}/invocations"]

Comment: What exactly is the error message?

Comment: @Marcin. Thanks for your comment. Please find the ERROR.  Invalid lambda function (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: 9cc5af0e-f6a1-4fe4-bad4-bdb066959928; Proxy: null)

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is not about ARN, but about API gateway **not having permissions** to invoke your function. You need to add something like the following:

```
{
  "AllowApiInvokations": {
    "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
    "Properties": {
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "FunctionName": "<function-name>" ,
      "Principal": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Thanks Marcin, but it is expecting to get the arn name when I used invokation, not just the lambda function. Please find the code which I used as per your suggestion. "AllowApiInvokations": {
         "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
         "Properties": {
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "FunctionName": "AspNetCoreFunction.Arn" ,
            "Principal": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
         }
       },

Comment: ERROR: 1 validation error detected: Value 'AspNetCoreFunction.Arn' at 'functionName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: (arn:(aws[a-zA-Z-]*)?:lambda:)?([a-z]{2}((-gov)|(-iso(b?)))?-[a-z]+-\d{1}:)?(\d{12}:)?(function:)?([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)(:(\$LATEST|[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+))? (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 02eb03d7-d249-4d40-bea2-4c75c7720557; Proxy: null)

Comment: @kaka You have to use `Fn::GetAtt` to get arn as you did in your original template.

Comment: @kaka How did it go? Still it does not work?

Comment: AllowApiInvokations:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName:
        Fn::GetAtt: AspNetCoreFunction.Arn
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com

Comment: Please find above code which I used in original template, still having same issue